# Meaning of clauses: "Failing at its formation,..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [Diplomacy: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT163&lpg=PT163&dq=The%20EU%20can%20enact%20binding%20laws%20with%20regard%20to%20welfare%20provision&source=bl&ots=0eqkse3J4F&sig=OZHF1su9sVsyWtog5cGbW4I99-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU4L61uOvLAhVP3mMKHcrRDNkQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=The%20EU%20can%20enact%20binding%20laws%20with%20regard%20to%20welfare%20provision&f=false)

> The EU can enact binding laws with regard to welfare provision, human rights, minimum wages, environmental standards, food safety standards, and more.
>   **After failing at its formation in 1993 to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia**, the EU has matured as a regional security actor.
>   The EU is moving towards a ‘security community’ in
>   Europe in which the Union, rather than member states acting as sovereign entities, pursues a European foreign policy and increasingly a security role in Europe and Africa.

What is relation between "failing at its formation in 1993" and "dealing with the break up of Yugoslavia" ? i think these two accident happened at same time (?) and author only wanted to give more historic information (?)
what do you think as native English speakers?

Comment: yorgun.  `1.`  Include your sources.  `2.` Use formatting to set block quotes apart.  `3.`  There are some non-native speakers here who have studied English extensively and can give excellent answers.  See http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/904/requests-for-native-speakers-to-answer-questions

Comment: @yorgun: to mark a question as answered, you click on the tick to the left of the answer that you think is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poorly written sentence. But *at its formation in 1993* are two  prepositional phrases that refer to the **EU** (which was formed in 1993).

You can delete either or both  prepositional phrases and the sentence would still be grammatical.

> After failing [at its formation][in 1993] to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia, the EU has matured as a regional security actor.

One might rewrite the sentence to make it clearer:

> After failing in 1993 (the year of its formation) to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia, the EU has matured as a regional security actor.

or

(*not so good:*)

> After failing to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia in 1993, the year of its formation, the EU has matured as a regional security actor.

The problem is that the reader can connect the prepositional phrases to *Yugoslavia* instead of the *EU*. The author might be trying to pack too much information in one sentence, which can lead to awkward phrasing, such as in the original sentence.

A better way might be to bring the subject of the sentence forward:

> Although the EU failed in 1993, the year of its formation, to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia, it has (since) matured as a regional security actor.

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to say it's a "poorly-written" sentence. It's aimed at native speakers, not people *learning* the language. Come to that, it's aimed at *relatively linguistically competent / literate* readers - it's not the register of the *Sun*, or the *Mirror*, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The "at it's formation in 1993" gives a timeframe of the failure.

Another way to write it would have been:

"When it was formed in 1993, it failed to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia."

Comment: thanks to all. how can i close this question as Answered?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is good answer:
Although the EU failed in 1993 (the year of its formation) to deal effectively with the break-up of the former Yugoslavia, it has (since) matured as a regional security actor.
 (1993 refers to both: 1-year od EU formation & 2-year of Yugoslavia break-up)